# Использование текущего значения инпута для отображения адекватного результата

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Нужно при разных значениях `input` выдавать каждый раз актуальную разницу между итогом (число 33, к примеру) и текущим значением в `input`. У меня любое вводимое значение отнимается от результата и записывается в результат. К примеру, ввожу 1 : результат 32, потом допечатываю 0, получается 10, а результат уже 22, а должен быть 33 - 10 = 23.

```js
function calc(){
  let input = document.getElementById('one');
let total = document.getElementById('total');
//console.log(input.value.length === 0);
input.addEventListener('input', function(){
  if(this.value.length === 0) {
    total.value = 33;
  }
  else if(this.value.length === 1) {
    total.value -= input.value;
  }
  else {
    total.value -= input.value;
  }
})
}
calc();
```

```html
One: <input type="text" id="one">
Total: <input type="text" id="total" value="33">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function calc(){
  let input = document.getElementById('one');
  let total = document.getElementById('total');
  let totalV = +total.value;
  input.addEventListener('input', function(){
    let value = +this.value || 0;
    total.value = totalV - value;
  });
}
calc();
```

```html
One: <input type="text" id="one">
Total: <input type="text" id="total" value="33">
```